# Is my SSD broken?

Tags: ssd, formatting, secure-erase

I've tried to delete all partition in my ssd using several method like disk manager, `diskpart` and 3rd party MiniTool Partition Wizard in windows 10, `gparted`, zero fill data `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc` and secure erase `hdparm`. But none of them work, like no effect at all.

Secure erase: refer to https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase, i've already set **frozen** state to **not frozen** state using `systemctl suspend`. When i run `hdparm --user-master u --security-erase password /dev/sdc`, it gives output:

```
/dev/sdc:
 Issuing SECURITY_ERASE command, password="password", user=user
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I have no idea what happen to my ssd . Should i throw my ssd into trash and get a new one?

Comment: It might be worthwhile to get a Windows 10 install ISO and use that to fully re-create Windows. It will create the necessary partitions - nothing for you to do. Do that and see if it works.

Comment: If you can't get it wiped by zeroing out with `dd`, I doubt that Secure Erase would help anyway -- so yes, I'd say it's broken (or at least bricked, or maybe locked accidentally). (Secure Erase could would indeed ATA unlock the drive though; but I highly doubt that it is case anyway. And you can lock/unlock/check with `hdparm` if it is.)

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502664/why-is-secure-erase-not-working-sg-io-bad-missing-sense-data

Check out this similar question on the Unix & Linux StackExchange site.

If the recommendations from that question don't help either I'm fairly certain the SSD is dead and needs to be replaced.